# CopyOnWriteArrayList vs ArrayList

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronized

Изучаю пакет java.util.concurrent. 
Перечитал куча статей, но никак не могу понять принципа потокобезопасности CopyOnWriteArrayList. Точнее принцип понял, что создается дубликат коллекции, и работа происходит именно с ней. Но на практике не могу это реализовать. 
Достойного примера не нашел. Вот в этой [статье](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-arraylist-copyonwritearraylist/)  в примере понятно только то что при использовании CopyOnWriteArrayList  при переборе итератором нельзя удалить элемент.
Самый главный вопрос. В каких случаях мы можем использовать потокобезопасность CopyOnWriteArrayList вместо синхронизации. Буду признателен за любой пример.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ArrayList совместно с синхронизацией в каком-нибудь высоконагруженном приложении будет работать медленнее, чем CopyOnWriteArrayList, так как обычный ArrayList будет блокироваться каким-либо потоком целиком и будет недоступен для остальных потоков. При этом, CopyOnWriteArrayList не требует блокировок потоками, так как каждый поток будет работать со своей копией листа. При использовании CopyOnWriteArrayList, при переборе итератором удалять элемент можно. Но это не отразится на том переборе, в котором происходит удаление, если например будете делать вывод на экран и удалять элемент, то получите вывод на экран первоначального списка целиком. Вот [здесь](http://java-online.ru/concurrent-collections.xhtml#copyonwritearraylist) приведен достаточно понятный пример работы CopyOnWriteArrayList.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList;

public class CopyOnWriteArrayListExample
{
    List<String> list;
    public CopyOnWriteArrayListExample()
    {
        List<String> lst = new ArrayList<String>();
        lst.add("Java");
        lst.add("J2EE");
        lst.add("J2SE");
        lst.add("Collection");
        lst.add("Concurrent");

        list = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<String>(lst);

        System.out.println("ЦИКЛ с изменением");
        printCollection(true);
        System.out.println("\nЦИКЛ без изменением");
        printCollection(false);

    }
    private void printCollection(boolean change)
    {
        Iterator<String> iterator = list.iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext()){
            String element = iterator.next();
            System.out.printf("  %s %n", element);
            if (change) { 
                if (element.equals("Collection")) {
                    list.add("Новая строка");
                    list.remove(element);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
        new CopyOnWriteArrayListExample();
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

На выходе получите такой результат:

```
ЦИКЛ с изменением
  Java 
  J2EE 
  J2SE 
  Collection 
  Concurrent 

ЦИКЛ без изменением
  Java 
  J2EE 
  J2SE 
  Concurrent 
  Новая строка
```

Comment: все стало намного яснее. Спасибо. Подскажите, правильно ли будет следующее утверждение: "При переборе коллекции CopyOnWriteArrayList работа происходит как с обычным Arraylist. Но при выполнении модифицирующих операций создается (клонируются) неизменяемая копия этого списка. Продолжение перебора происходит именно в этой копии. Все изменения этого списка не касаются. А изменения вносятся уже в оригинальный список.

Comment: @МаксимБродский да, верно, пока вы не модифицируете CopyOnWriteArrayList, никаких копий не создается.

Comment: Все равно не могу понять. Посмотрите первый ответ на вот этот вопрос https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28979488/difference-between-copyonwritearraylist-and-synchronizedlist.  Там написано: The add method will always create a copy of the existing array and do the modification on the copy and then finally update the volatile reference of the array to point to this new array. And that's why we have the name "CopyOnWriteArrayList" - makes copy when you write into it.. This also avoids the ConcurrentModificationException. Тоесть изменения вносяться в копию списка? Как я понял он не изменяемый.

Comment: @МаксимБродский ну и что не так?)) Вот перевод: "Метод add всегда создает копию имеющегося массива и делает изменения в копии, а затем обновляет ссылку на измененный массив...". Вы все правильно поняли, сначала делаются изменения в копии, а затем ссылка на изначальный массив начинает ссылаться на измененный.

Comment: вот допустим ситуация. Один поток начал перебирать этот список. В определенній момент этот поток производит добавление. Сразу создаеться копия этого списка и уже в нем производяться изменения. Но в тот же момент в этот список хочет добавить изменеия другой поток и тоже делает копию первоначального списка, так как первый не успел еще внести изменения. После этого первый поток вносит изменения и присваивает оригинальному списку ссылку на измененный список. А второй поток вносит свои изменения и присавивает тому же списку новую  ссылку. Получается данные перезатираются. ЖЕСТЬ.

Comment: @МаксимБродский я не думаю, что какие-то данные пропадут. первый поток внесет изменения в лист и изменится ссылка на него, второй поток уже получит ссылку на измененный лист и будет вносить изменения в него. Методы изменения листа, такие как add, синхронизированы, они лочатся на объекте ReentrantLock. Вот упрощенный алгоритм работы метода add, чисто для понимания: сначала блокируется лист, затем делается его копия, добавляется новый элемент, изменяется ссылка, лист разблокируется. Пока не прошли изменения и не изменилась ссылка, другой поток не сможет внести изменения в лист из-за блокировки.

Comment: Ну наконец-то! СПАСИБО!